# Can thyroid disease be reversed without using lifelong medicine?

Tags: thyroid, fatigue, gluten

From what I see online is that there may be a connection between leaky gut, thyroid and cholesterol. Docs prefer to give medicines usually life long but I saw that thyroid disease can be reversed with healthy lifestyle and diet changes and it mainly depends on the gut health. One interesting case I read was the person was cured of thyroid disease after fixing the leaky gut by going gluten free. Could anyone shed some light on this topic particularly autoimmune thyroid disease.
http://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/9515902

Comment: I cannot fully answer this as I don't know of studies that directly link them.  That said, there is a supplement, called Bromelain you can ask your doctor about that helped me with thyroid levels and with IBS, and there seems to be some connection to assisting with cholesterol. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3529416/

Comment: Hi @threetimes thank you for your desire to help with this answer, but you are offering medical advice and that is discouraged here on HealthSE. Check out [this meta for a detailed explanation of why we don't give medical advice](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor?cb=1). Check out [this meta on why we should avoid answering personal advice questions.](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/753/please-dont-answer-questions-that-are-off-topic?cb=1)

Comment: @threetimes even well-intended as it is, your advice is toward the top of the slippery slope of recommending treatment.  If the question were completely devoid of personal advice (clinical information) then a variation on your question would be appropriate, especially with the paper cited.

Comment: @Sunny welcome to SE! This question is presenting lab values and symptoms, thoughts on what diagnoses you might have, and is asking for information and treatment recommendations. Check out [this meta on reasons why we can't give medical advice and why your question qualifies as medical advice request.](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor?cb=)

Comment: If you rephrase your entire question to ask the underlying question whether there is evidence for ways that autoimmune-related hypothyroidism conditions can be reversed in any way, rather than relying on lifelong thyroid supplementation, then your question could be answered. Otherwise I must vote to close it for now.  I'll retract my vote if adjusted!

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to this forum. I have rephrased it. Let me know if any changes required.

Comment: @threetimes, thank you for your suggestuon. Was it recommended lifelong or just a course.

Comment: No worries, Sunny!  I fixed some of your grammar too.  Interesting source article.  FYI docs usually prefer giving thyroid hormone replacement because it is proven to work.  Other methods don't have as much evidence, though they may build evidence enough to become mainstream eventually.  Alternative approaches to autoimmune disease is an interesting topic and starting to be explored in the literature more seriously, so I expect to see more as time goes along.  I'm not sure you'll find someone well versed in evidence-based alternative therapies here to get the answer you're seeking.

Comment: Having thyroid imbalance isn't something to mess with, one can be pretty sick with too high or too low levels, so anyone trying something outside of current recommended best practices should be monitored closely. But based on the pathophys of AI thyroiditis, I have my doubts that autoimmune destruction of the thyroid gland can be reversed.  Perhaps early in disease course it can be curbed.  But that's speculation.